# bash command in python not working

Tags: linux, bash, unix, script, python

I would like to run a bash command from python. My code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(('ifconfig -s'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()[0]
lcd.message(output)
sleep(2)
lcd.clear()
```

This executes "ifconfig -s" and the output is displayed on a 16x2 LCD. Too much info for that display. So the new command is:

```
ifconfig | awk '$1 {print $1}' FS="  " ORS=,
```

Works perfectely in a shell but I have problems in the python code.
When I simply change the "ifconfig -s" with this I get errors. I think this is due to the >'< quote signs...

Could you help me making the new ifconfig work with the old code?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the single quotes?

Comment: First, consider using backticks (`) and escape quotes of any type within the concatenated string where appropriate, and concatenating the command into a string before passing it to Popen.

Answer (score 0):

```
process = subprocess.Popen( 
                            r"ifconfig | awk '$1 {print $1}' FS=' ' ORS=,", 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            shell=True
                           )
output = process.communicate()[0]
lcd.message(output)
sleep(2)
lcd.clear()
```

If 'shell=True' and a sequence is passed, command and its arguments must be listed as individual items of the sequence like ('ifconfig','-s').
If a string is passed as above ipc is easily achieved because the whole string is passed to shell when shell is true.
To pass sequence and do 'ipc',

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen( 
                           [ 'ifconfig'],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE
                           )
process2 = subprocess.Popen( 
                           [ 'awk','$1 {print $1}', 'FS=" "', 'ORS=,'],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=process1.stdout
                           )
output = process2.communicate()[0]
lcd.message(output)
sleep(2)
lcd.clear()
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.